# Postfix TLS issue

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to enable TLS on Postfix but the daemon is crashing:

```
Sep 16 16:00:38 core postfix/master[1689]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 1694 killed by signal 11
Sep 16 16:00:38 core postfix/master[1689]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

This is OpenVZ container (CentOS 6.3 x86_64) with two IPs

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = 
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = 
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache.db
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,   reject_invalid_hostname,    permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,   permit_sasl_authenticated,  reject_unauth_pipelining,   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    reject_invalid_hostname,    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,   reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,   reject_unauth_destination   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,   permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,  reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,   permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

---

```
# postconf -a
cyrus
dovecot
```

---

```
# ldd /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff10dfe000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f8a01c2c000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f8a01a1d000)
    libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007f8a017f0000)
    libmysqlclient.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16 (0x00007f8a014ea000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8a01266000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f8a0104b000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f8a00df0000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f8a00a56000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8a00851000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8a0063b000)
    libdb-4.7.so => /lib64/libdb-4.7.so (0x00007f8a002c7000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f8a000ad000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f89ffe93000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89ffb00000)
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007f89ff8c3000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f89ff697000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f89ff35b000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f89ff134000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f89fef30000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f89fed2b000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f89feaed000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f89fe8d0000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f89fe699000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f89fe456000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f89fe177000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f89fdf73000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f89fdd46000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8a02102000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f89fdae4000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f89fd8d8000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f89fd6d5000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f89fd4b5000)
```

---

```
# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf | grep -v "^#"
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
smtps   inet n   -   n   - - smtpd
   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
   -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender=yes
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
   -o broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes 
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

---

**Requested information from the comment:**

```
# { postconf -d; postconf -d; postconf -n; } | sort | uniq -u
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = 
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,   reject_invalid_hostname,    permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,   permit_sasl_authenticated,  reject_unauth_pipelining,   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    reject_invalid_hostname,    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,   reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,   reject_unauth_destination,  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,   permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,  reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,   permit
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

Postfix version:

```
# postconf mail_version
mail_version = 2.6.6
```

Logs (telnet 127.0.0.1 25):

```
Sep 18 14:07:25 core postfix/postfix-script[4078]: starting the Postfix mail system
Sep 18 14:07:25 core postfix/master[4079]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep 18 14:07:49 core postfix/smtpd[4083]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Sep 18 14:07:49 core postfix/tlsmgr[4084]: open smtpd TLS cache btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
Sep 18 14:07:49 core postfix/tlsmgr[4084]: tlsmgr_cache_run_event: start TLS smtpd session cache cleanup
Sep 18 14:07:49 core postfix/master[4079]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 4083 killed by signal 11
Sep 18 14:07:49 core postfix/master[4079]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Comment: Is your Postfix chrooted?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm wondering if some package/library is missing for TLS - works fine with TLS disabled

Comment: Does your Postfix support Dovecot SASL? Check with `postconf -a`. If Dovecot is supported, next thing I'd try would probably be [enabling verbose logging](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#verbose) in Postfix. Be warned that Postfix gets *really* chatty when you do that.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info. It does support Dovecot and I don't see any errors with verbose login enabled. I'm wondering if this is some issue with Openssl library. This is OpenVZ container so maybe there is something wrong with the template?

Comment: Please attach your master.cf, so we can see how you start your smptd!

Comment: I've attached the requested information. Please note that it works fine with TLS disabled.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: The problem is not with SASL, nor will the suggestion to enable verbose logging help him here.

Comment: Can you post /etc/dovecot.conf?

Answer (score 2):

> smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache.db

NOTE that smtp != smtp***d***.

You have not set smtpD_tls_session_cache_database, and this setting [***has no default***](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database).

Add it and reload.

EDIT: meh, it's not actually required. Oh well, perhaps somme more logging will give us a clue.

RE-EDIT: please do the following:

- stop postfix: `postfix stop`
- clear the logs with `mv /var/log/mail.log ~/mail.log.bak` and **restart your syslog service**
- show the output of `{ postconf -d; postconf -d; postconf -n; } | sort | uniq -u`, as this will show us what was set in main.cf that is *not a default*
- show the output of `postconf mail_version`
- edit main.cf and set `inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1` and `debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1`
- start postfix: `postfix start`
- make a connection using telnet to the local server: `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`
- observe what happens and post the clean logs from the beginning.

Comment: Shall I keep the other directive `smtp_tls_session_cache_database` as well? It still doesn't work. The Postfix demon keeps crashing every time I'm trying to access it via telnet. I'm not sure what's going on here. `warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling` - is it mean that there is some bad/old directive in the config file?

Comment: It looks like `smtpd_use_tls = yes` causing the problem. I've actually set both these directives: `smtp_use_tls = yes
, smtpd_use_tls = yes`

Comment: The `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt` also doesn't work

Comment: `smtpd_use_tls = yes` makes the SMTP *server* require TLS. `smtp_use_tls = yes` makes Postfix' SMTP *client* require TLS (the component that sends outgoing mail to upstream MTAs). You probably want to disable the latter, but I doubt that it's the cause of the issue.

Comment: What else I can do to debug this issue? It's strange that when I enable TLS on Postfix, Dovecot also not working: `Sep 17 21:56:50 server dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=MyIP, lip=ServerIP, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol`

Comment: You need to separate these symptoms, as they are not caused by the same thing. Postfix smtpd(8) not starting up means you don't have a mail server.

Comment: I've added the requested information. There is not to much info in the logs.

Comment: OK I think I finally know what cuse the issue however I don't know the solution yet. I've tried lots of different configurations - I've created another virtual guest with the same settings - it works fine and the only difference is that I'm using Percona MySQL server on the machine where Postfix is not working and this seems to be the cause of this problem: http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/09/why-does-percona-cause-ssl-issues-in-postfix/

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I'm comparing this to my working Postfix+Dovecot solution that is using TLS just fine at this point. The version is newer than you're reporting as this is running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
# postconf mail_version
mail_version = 2.9.3
```

Now if I check only my non-default `smtpd_*` settings I have the following:

```
# postconf -n |grep ^smtpd_
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.example.net.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.example.net.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Another difference between my system and yours is that I am running in a chroot so my `master.cf` has the following for comparison:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

As you can tell by reading that I'm only listening on 25/tcp (smtp) and 587/tcp (submission) as there is no need for 465/tcp (smtps) as 25/tcp will support STARTTLS and 587/tcp requires STARTTLS.

About the only real significant difference I could tell from my `master.cf` and yours was that you have smtp starting with `smtpd -v` and I simply have `smtpd`

I question what caused the log entries for postfix/tlsmgr as simply telneting to port 25 should not have even initiated the TLS connection unless the STARTTLS command was given once connected and then to properly test that you would be better off testing using:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -starttls smtp -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
```

Notes for my SSL setup: I instal the `ca-certificates` package and then place my certificate under `/etc/ssl/certs` and my key under `/etc/ssl/private`. I then stick my intermediate CA under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and run `update-ca-certificates. This re-generates the`ca-certificates.crt`and creates the proper symlinks under`/etc/ssl/certs`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turned out there is a issue with library (libmysqlclient.so) provided by Percona repo: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1028240